# apache camel request response and how to route to next transformer

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

The concept of routing is nice in theory but in practice, I am a bit confused.  I have a CXF method in my webservice

```
public Response someMethod(Request r) {
}
```

what I don't get is I need to route the Request to some further node so am I really supposed to do that in the java code or will camel generate an interface(asynch hopefully) that I can wire that node up to some transformer to a next node validator to some store and forward, etc and then finally have the store and forward reply with a Response that is somehow sent out the socket the Request came in from originally.

In the above method, I am forced to return the response back to the client in that method, right?

If I am supposed to put the code in the webservices method, is there some camel context I am supposed to call into?

Also, I want the "RAW" parameters of the SOAP method call and don't want to deal with SOAP Header and then also need to expose some REST apis as well that just accept a String.

EDIT: The proxy example from the answer below is the closest I have seen but even that one if I want to short cut and not even call the real webservice at an earlier node in the pipeline, I can't.  I seem to have to call the end webservice code which is not wanted as we don't have any webservice code.  We are trying to run it through existing pojos from a webservice call.  If the validation node fails, we want to return a response, if it succeeds we want to forward the request on to another node where if that node fails we return a response or if it succeeds we want to forward the request on.  There seems to be nothing for this???  Also, this seems like a pretty typical case to me so I am surprised or I am not getting something with all these ESB frameworks(mule, camel so far).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never solved, we dropped camel as it is quite a pain compared to rolling your own.

Comment: Considering doing the same. Camel seems impossible to setup for anything non-trivial. Even the examples from the website don't work.

Comment: Try using Guice DI....it makes it cake to rewrite components and roll your own such that all component directly hook up and there is no framework making changes super simple as you can just rewire stuff up...it basically does as little as possible for you(and I like how the binding stuff unlike spring is done in java not xml).

Comment: I've used Guice before, I actually prefer Spring (in which you can also bind using only Java). But that is not my issue, my issue is with Camel. I finally solved my problem but it was very hard because documentation is either wrong, incomplete or outdated. And very scattered.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this official Example, it'll show how to do this](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html)
[Or this Cxf proxy example if you want the RAW request](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html)

If you are in a Spring MVC webapp already - you could perhaps do this a bit easier with Spring WS and Jaxb. But that is a matter of taste. [Example code here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/examples/camel-example-spring-ws/)

Comment: sorry, been through that example and even stepped through the examples.  May of the examples expose a soap interface that do the actual work instead of being an endpoint and passing work to some next node through routing.  Either I and my teammates are missing something big or these examples just don't hit on this scenario(Adding more info to question above as well)